# Remplazar palabra del string si despues de esa palabra viene un numero (y mantener el numero!)

Tags: python, regex

La idea es obtener una frase en string y reemplazar la palabra "del" por "/" SOLO EN EL CASO de que despues de la palabra "del" venga un numero de 4 digitos

Mi codigo de ejemplo:

```py
frase = input()

frase = re.sub(r' del\s*\d{4}','/', frase)

print(frase)
```

El problema es que el sub reemplaza tambien el año.

**Input de ejemplo:** *"Nos vemos en mayo del 2021. Acuerdate del secreto"*

**Respuesta de python:** *"Nos vemos en mayo/. Acuerdate del secreto"*

**Lo que quiero:** *"Nos vemos en mayo/2021. Acuerdate del secreto"*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Si vas a usar expresiones regulares, puedes usar directamente `re.sub`. En este caso debe ir acompañada de lookahead para evitar que el número sea substituido:

```
import re

frase = "Nos vemos en mayo del 2021. Acuerdate del secreto"
frase = re.sub(r'\s*del\s*(?=\d{4}(?!\d))', "/", frase)
```

> ```
> >>> frase
> 'Nos vemos en mayo/2021. Acuerdate del secreto'
> ```

- **`?=`** -> lookahead, confirma que lo que sigue inmediatamente a la posición actual en la cadena es:

  - **`\d{4}`** -> cuatro dígitos
  - **`?!\d`**-> no seguidos de otro dígito.

el lookahead no se incluye en el match, pero si influye en él, en este caso si lo anterior no ésta seguido de cuatro dígitos, ni más ni menos el match será negativo y no se sustituirá. Es decir, aunque se encuentre un "del" rodeado de espacios, el match será nulo si no se sigue de cuatro dígitos, si se sigue de ellos el match será " del " solo, sin incluir los dígitos.

`re.sub` por defecto substituirá todas las coincidencias  que encuentre en la cadena siempre que no se solapen. Se puede limitar con el argumento `count`. Por ejemplo, `re.sub("", "", "", count=1)` solo reemplazara la primera que encuentre, si la encuentra.

Comment: Me funcionó a la perfección. Había encontrado una solucion pero sin duda esta es mucho mas eficiente. En una sola linea cumple con mis requisitos. Gracias!

Answer (score 1):

Prueba aver si esto resuelve tu problema:

```
frase = "Nos vemos en mayo del 2021. Acuerdate del secreto"

s = frase.split(" del ", 1)

try:
    numb = int(s[1][:4])
    fraseNueva = s[0] + '/' + s[1]
    print(fraseNueva)

except:
    print(frase)
```

La funcion split convierte tu variable frase en una lista usando la primera palabra del como separador.

Entonces `s` es una lista que contiene `['Nos vemos en mayo', '2021. Acuerdate del secreto']`

Con el `try` intento convertir en numero entero los primeros cuatro caracteres de el elemento en indice 1 de la lista. Si no hay 4 numeros o más dará error y la `fraseNueva` no llegará a crearse. Esta `fraseNueva` solamente concatena los dos elementos de la lista quitando los primeros cuatro caracteres del segundo elemento.

En caso de que no hayan 4 numeros el `try` dara error y se ejecutará el `except`.

Comment: Convendría una pequeña explicación, aquí puedes leer [answer]

Comment: Es una buena solución pero la de FJSevilla lo resuelve todo en una linea usando el re.sub como en mi codigo original. Igual gracias por la ayuda!

Answer (score 0):

Encontré una solución.

```py
frase = input()

replace_del = re.search(r' del\s*\d{4}', frase)
if replace_del:
    replace_del = replace_del.group()
    frase = frase.replace(replace_del, '/'+replace_del[-4:]) #Reemplaza el caso que encontró en la frase con '/' y los ultimos 4 caracteres del caso (que seria el numero de 4 digitos)

print(frase)
```

En este caso solo sirve para el primer caso que encuentre. Me sirve con esto.

**Input de ejemplo:** *"Nos vemos en mayo del 2021. Acuerdate del secreto"*

**Respuesta:** *"Nos vemos en mayo/2021. Acuerdate del secreto"*

Comment: justo el uso de replace era lo que te iba a comentar